# Recode multiple variables into one and assign new values based on their former names

Tags: spss

So as per the title, I have a dataset with rows organised by ID for each household, where each household has at most 7 kids. The rows are Child1.Age, Child1.Sex, Child1.Immunisation and so forth for up to Child7.

I would like to recode the variables such that I have all the children in variables like Children.Age, Household.ChildCount, Children.BirthOrder, Children.Immunisation, Children.Sex, and so forth. As this can't be done through the "Recode variables into different variables" option, how would I do this using either SPSS syntax or Python, while preserving the identities of multiple children from a household?

Comment: Use `VARSTOCASES` to reshape the data from wide to long, and make a new id for each child. If that is not sufficient, you will need to be more specific what you want in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Complete this command with the rest of the needed variables:

```
Varstocases 
/make Children.Age from Child1.Age Child2.Age Child3.Age Child4.Age ...
/make Children.Sex from Child1.Sex Child2.Sex Child3.Sex Child4.Sex...
/index=childID(Children.Age).
compute childID=substr(childID,1,6).
```

Then use `aggregate` with `addvariables` to count the children in each family.